# How to get the tags of the rule matched by mmnormalize

Tags: rsyslog

I wrote some liblognormalize rules to parse postgresql logs.
My rule file contains two rules and each rule has some tags like:

```
rule=POSTGRESQL,CHECKPOINT: ....
rule=POSTGRESQL,SLOWQUERY: ....
```

After running mmnormalize in my rsyslog configuration, I would like to know which rule actually matched the log line being processed. The simplest solution would be to get the tags. I know that mmnormalize export some variables like *$parsesuccess*. Is there any variable containing the tags of the rule used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know where I found it in the docs but in a rsyslog config file that I wrote some time ago I found that I can access the list of tags that liblognorm assigns to a message via `event.tags` in rsyslog.

I have for example

```
template( # ...
  property(name="$!event.tags")
)
```

or

```
if $!event.tags != "" then { # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution seems to be the `annotate` feature:

```
rule=POSTGRESQL,CHECKPOINT: ....
annotate=CHECKPOINT:+checkpoint="complete"
```

Basically the annotate line will add a field `checkpoint` containing the value `complete` to all the log lines matching the rules with a tag `CHECKPOINT`

Found it [here](https://github.com/rsyslog/liblognorm/blob/master/doc/configuration.rst#log-annotations)